# Have table with sticky column with border radius but while scrolling the table header showing the background

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the reference image for the issue, green column is sticky have scroll while scrolling the background blue showing around the sticky column because of border radius how hide that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhDVf.png)

Clear out the blue background while scrolling

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first simple way is to give the `blue` the same border radius as the `green`.

The second way is to use the `getBoundingClientRect()` function to find the position of the two elements and dynamically convert the radius of `blue` to the same value as `green` if the top is the same.